# Sqlite "CREATE TABLE" SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is wrong with this SQL statement (for SQLITE):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "history" 
(
    "inscode" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "yyyyymmdd" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "basic_data" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "instrument_state" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "static_thresholds" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "trades" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "closing_price" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "best_limits" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "client_type" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "shareholders" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("inscode", "yyyymmdd")
) WITHOUT ROWID
```

I get this error message:

> Execution finished with errors.
> Result: expressions prohibited in PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraints

Comment: Hi - what about thar error message don’t you understand? I’m not sure how it could be any clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an unfortunate interaction of [quirk 8](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html) in sqlite3 and there being a typo in the column definition:

- The column definition says `"yyyyymmdd"`; notice that there are five "y", not four. This is a typo.
- Due to historical reasons, "SQLite will also interpret a double-quotes string as string literal if it does not match any valid identifier. This misfeature means that a misspelled double-quoted identifier will be interpreted as a string literal, rather than generating an error."; see the [docs here](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html).

Since the `PRIMARY KEY` clause refers to `"yyyymmdd"` (four "y"), but the column definition being `"yyyyymmdd"` (five "y"), the above mentioned quirk kicks in and `"yyyyymmdd"` is interpreted as a string literal, which is the "expression in the primary key" that sqlite3 is then complaining about.

The solution is to fix the typo in the column definition...